# "Having trouble firing up popup.js on getting call from content.js"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to extension building. Just trying to build an extension which keeps counts on the number of times a button is clicked and show the number on popup. Appreciate the help.

manifest.json

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Audit counts",
  "description": "Check your productivity",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon-128.png",
    "default_title": "know your counts",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Audit counts</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body id="popup_body">
    <h4 id="greet">Audit counts</h4>
    <h2 id="counts">00</h2>
    <button id="show">Show counts</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</body>

</html>
```

content.js

```
var button = document.getElementById("nav-logobar-greeting");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage("Hello, World");

}, false);
```

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (response, sender, sendResponse) {
  alert("running");
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#counts").text(response);
  });

});
```

I expected "Hello, World" replacing "00" in popup.

Comment: The popup runs **only** when it's shown so you can't send messages to it while it's hidden. You can send a message to your background script and it can show the number in the extension icon badge using chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you elaborate on that. I want to make the counter value to zero on clicking 'reset' which is on popup.html.

Comment: Think of the popup as of a separate page in a small tab that looks like the popup. It exists only when shown. Now that you know it, you can think how to implement your extension.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the inputs. Made use of ```chrome.browserAction.setBadge``` and it served my requirement of showing the value. Just wanted to know if there are any other methods to dynamically show DOM value of any page on popup. Because now I know that popup only runs when it is open.Thanks.